# React Native Relay Issue

Tags: react-native, relayjs, relay, react-native-ios

I'm following along with this tutorial: [enter link description here](http://www.mot.la/2016-05-08-getting-started-with-react-native-and-relay.html), but I'm getting an issue when I enter these lines of codes:

```
import Relay, { 
  Route,
  RootContainer,
  DefaultNetworkLayer
} from 'react-relay'

Relay.injectNetworkLayer(new DefaultNetworkLayer('http://localhost:3000/graphql'))
```

Specifically, the last line is giving me this error:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install react-relay --save
```

will not install the same thing as the tutorial author installed if there was an update to this package in the time in between. By default this commands installs the latest.

Once you figured out what version to use , add that requirement with the `@X.Y.Z` notation.

It could also be because, there is a different babel/webpack/rollup set up that messes up the import.

"react-relay": "0.9.2" is used for the demo here https://github.com/relayjs/relay-examples/blob/master/TodoMVC/package.json